# Issue with Zend Framework 2 UnitTesting tutorial: status code 500

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

I've built the [ZF2 "Getting Started" application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/overview.html) and am trying to apply the tests from the [ZF2 UnitTesting tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/unittesting.html) to it. Now I have a trouble with this simple test:

[project]/module/Album/test/AlbumTest/Controller/AlbumControllerTest.php

```
<?php
namespace AlbumTest\Controller;
...
class AlbumControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    ...
    public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/album');
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);

        $this->assertModuleName('Album');
        $this->assertControllerName('Album\Controller\Album');
        $this->assertControllerClass('AlbumController');
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('album');
    }
}
```

command line: /var/www/sandbox/zf2sandbox/module/Album/test/

```
# phpunit
PHPUnit 3.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/sandbox/zf2sandbox/module/Album/test/phpunit.xml

F....

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 10.00Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) AlbumTest\Controller\AlbumControllerTest::testIndexActionCanBeAccessed
Failed asserting response code "200", actual status code is "500"

/var/www/sandbox/zf2sandbox/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:373
/var/www/sandbox/zf2sandbox/module/Album/test/AlbumTest/Controller/AlbumControllerTest.php:49

FAILURES!
Tests: 5, Assertions: 11, Failures: 1.
```

So, the `assertResponseStatusCode(200)` is failed, since the status code is `500`. **Why?**

When I call this path in the Browser (http://zf2sandbox.sandbox.loc/album), it works:

[image]

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is just in the next heading in the tutorial you followed. [A failing test case.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#a-failing-test-case)

So according to it, you need configure service manager.

```
$serviceManager = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();
$serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);
$serviceManager->setService('Album\Model\AlbumTable', $albumTableMock);
```

Also adding this one is very helpful to get proper error in unit testing as mention in link.

```
protected $traceError = true;
```

Comment: Ok but how is possible for me to works and return status 302 without mocks? The strange behaviour is that on localhost it works but when I run the same code on my hosting I see status 500. What can be the reason?